# How do I find a unit vector of another in Java?

Tags: java, vector

I'm writing a Java formula based on this tutorial: [2-D elastic collisions without Trigonometry](http://www.imada.sdu.dk/~rolf/Edu/DM815/E10/2dcollisions.pdf). I am in the section **"Elastic Collisions in 2 Dimensions"**. Part of step 1 says:

> Next, find the unit vector of n, which we will call un. This is done by dividing by the magnitude of n.

My below code represents the normal vector of 2 objects (I'm using a simple array to represent the normal vector).

```
int[] normal = new int[2];
normal[0] = ball2.x - ball1.x;
normal[1] = ball2.y - ball1.y;
```

I am unsure what the tutorial means by dividing the magnitude of *n* to get the *un*.

What is *un*? How can I calculate it with my Java array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, using arrays is not the best way to represent Vector information in Java. Second, use floats. Take a look at [LibGDX Vector2 class](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector2.html).

The magnitude of a vector is it's length, obtainable with the Pythagorean theorem:

```
a² = b² + c²
```

in your case, you can obtain it by:

```
float[] normal = new float[2];
normal[0] = ball2.x - ball1.x;
normal[1] = ball2.y - ball1.y;
float magnitude = (float)Math.Sqrt(normal[0]*normal[0] + normal[1] * normal[1]);
float[] un = new float[2];
un[0] = normal[0] / magnitude;
un[1] = normal[1] / magnitude;
```

let me reassure you that using Arrays is NOT good. With a properly Vector class it should be like:

```
Vector2 normal = new Vector2();
normal.set(ball2);
normal.sub(ball1);
Vector2 un = new Vector2();
un.set(normal);
un.normalize();
```

If you were going to a language where Operator overloading is possible:

```
Vector2 normal = ball2 - ball1;
Vector2 un = normal / normal.length();
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the help! I will try to implement this and let you know if it works out. Currently I am not using LibGDX library so I cannot use Vector2, Thanks!

Comment: I took your advice and started to work with Vector2, while I am not using LIBGDX, I did copy over the Vector2 class and am using that for calculations. Definetly a better approach to arrays. Cheers!